# .htaccess: Codeigniter + Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am developing site on Codeigniter and want to "connect" it with Wordpress.
So the URL structure will be

```
SITE-URL
-SITE-URL/folder1/
--SITE-URL/folder1/some-link
-URL/folder2/
```

...etc

What I need to do, is when Codeigniter throws 404 error, the content is taken from Wordpress website(same relative URL) without any redirects for end user.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do this with .htaccess since .htaccess can only do re-directions before the content is served, meaning before Codeigniter has responded to the request. So when Codeigniter generates a 404, it's returning content an .htaccess isn't processed.

What you would need to do is generate a 404 controller that either does a redirect, which you don't want, but would be the easiest. Or the 404 controller would then have to load in wordpress and process the request through there. Something similar to proxy, but it will need to be done with PHP.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for the answer. I guess, the logic could be the following: I set up all the routes to controllers I use in Codeigniter and all other routes (which are basically 404s) should request Wordpress's folder.